# Showing column twice in a query, second time showing data post update/set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

For testing purposes I'm wondering if the following two selects could ever be combined:

```
begin transaction

select  x
from    example_table

update  example_table
set     x = 'new value'

select  x
from    example_table

rollback transaction
```

Essentially, I'd like to see a result output like:

> Column Name, Updated Column Name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can do in using [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause (SQL Server 2005 +)

```
use tempdb
go

create table #tbl (i int)

insert into #tbl values (10),(20),(30),(40)

update #tbl
set i=i+1
output deleted.i i_old,inserted.i  i_updated

drop table #tbl
```

From Books OnLine

> **OUTPUT** Clause returns information from, or expressions based on, each
>   row affected by an INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement.

...

> **DELETED** is a column prefix that specifies the value deleted by the
>   update or delete operation. Columns prefixed with DELETED reflect the
>   value before the UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is completed.

...

> **INSERTED** is a column prefix that specifies the value added by the
>   insert or update operation. Columns prefixed with INSERTED reflect the
>   value after the UPDATE, INSERT, or MERGE statement is completed but
>   before triggers are executed.

**EDITED**

```
begin transaction

update  example_table
set     x = 'new value'
output deleted.x old_value, inserted.x new_value

rollback transaction
```

Comment: I'm unsure if I'm explaining myself properly. I'm actually updating a pre-existing table and want to show an output of the original value as well as the new value that I've changed it to.

Comment: @Michael That's what my example demonstrates. I create, populate with data and drop table just to give an example. Actually you need just `UPDATE...`

Comment: I apologize but I'm a bit confused by this - could you do this again using the example in the original post?